# Is that safe to keep only armeabi-v7a for an android apk

Tags: android, android-ndk, snappydb

I have an android APK that use a native library ([`snappydb`](http://snappydb.com/)). 
The native libraries takes a lot of spaces, so I want to keep only the `snappydb` for armeabi-v7a architectures?

I know it's not 100% safe to remove `snappydb` for other architectures, so my question is: how unsafe it is? (how many devices/users will I lost?)

Just for reference, the minimal sdk version that my app support is 16 (JELLY_BEAN).

Comment: Your question isn't really clear—your wording is imprecise and unclear. Do you mean that you only want to compile and bundle `snappydb` for armeabi-v7a, and not include the same lib for other architectures? What do you mean 'remove other native libs'—what other libs?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I mean not include `snappydb` for other architectures.

Comment: I'll leave this as a comment because I can't give a well-supported answer. To my knowledge, almost all Android devices are ARMv5 or ARMv7 (not sure how many are v5). There are a couple x86 (Intel) tablets as of last year, and I think a few MIPS devices started coming our years ago, but I don't hear about them much and to my knowledge they're not popular. I'd be surprised if non-ARM is more than 5-10% market share (but again, this is anecdotal, I don't have any data right now). Note however that some of the x86 devices are Samsung devices.

Comment: @Laogeodritt sounds reasonable, thank your for the information. So it looks like if I keep armeabi-v7a, armeabi, x86, most of the devices will be covered?

Comment: You cannot attach a debugger to a running APK with armeabi-v7a architecture in Android Studio 2.2.  It simply won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably not gain too much from arm-v7a optimization, and currently there is no compelling reason to include 64-bit build. But MIPS and X86 owners will thank you if you keep their devices covered.

Comment: Hi Alex, what do you mean 'not gain too much from arm-v7a optimization' ?

Comment: Normally, native code compiled for **armeabi** will run fine on devices that support **armeabi-v7a**, but not otherwise. Number crunching algorithms may be much more efficient when compiled for **armeabi-v7a**, but this is much less relevant for database library.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using Gradle's *productFlavors* to produce different APKs per ABI, as some ABI may include some assembly code optimization (SSE4, SSE5, Arm Neon etc,)

```
android {
    ...

    flavorDimensions "abi", "version"

    productFlavors {
        freeapp {
            flavorDimension "version"
            ...
        }

        x86 {
            flavorDimension "abi"
            ...
        }
    }
 }
```

Or if you're using the experimental Gradle plugin 
`'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.1.0'`

```
android.productFlavors {
        create ("arm7") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "armeabi-v7a"
        }
        create ("arm8") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "arm64-v8a"
        }
        create ("x86-32") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "x86"
        }
        // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
        // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
        // build one including all productFlavors
        create("fat")
    }
```

Comment: Very true. The cost of jiggling with few architectures is minimal, but otherwise for some users there is no way to use the app.

Comment: @nabil-hachicha different APKs per ABI is a indeed a good solution for Google Play. However for other market that doesn't support multiple apk, it seems hard to figure out a way to distribution the my app correctly. And update is also tough problem